# Перифразы к слову "Россия"

Tags: фигуры

Предложите, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь перифразы к слову "Россия".

> Выделил перифразы. Чтобы ответить на вопрос конкретнее, нужно знать в каком контексте этот перифраз должен употребляться.

Благодарю Вас, [[@Марк Из](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7)](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7), за ценные рекомендации. Контекст разумного объема вряд ли позволит Вам определить необходимые коннотации, сопутствующие значению описательного выражения, заменяющего однословное наименование, поэтому я сама определю их как отсутствующие. Я ищу не окрашенное эмоционально выражение, вроде "Петра творенье" или  "Третий Рим".

> Страна незаходящего солнца (размеры), двуглавого орла (Восток - Запад) и таинственной духовности (духовный оплот мира).

Блестяще! Одно лучше другого! Но мне больше всего нравится "Страна таинственной духовности". Жаль, Вы это выражение не пояснили. 
Простите, я никак иначе не могу сейчас засвидетельствовать свою признательность: какие-то технические неисправности значительно ограничивают мои привилегии. Кто-нибудь, отметьте там за меня этот ответ, а я, когда разберусь со своими неисправностями, присоединюсь.

> Знать бы, действительно, контекст

Будь по-вашему, контекст: *"В своё время завершением и без того не располагающего образа служил монокль, но когда на территории России установилась советская власть, Лаврентий Оскарович мудро оставил эту буржуазную моду".*

Думаю, ясно, что выдержка принадлежит сочинению сатирической направленности, однако в процитированном отрезке ни Россия, ни что бы то ни было иное в сатирическом ключе не изображается. Подойдет любое изящное, предпочтительно нейтральное выражение, всем известное или только что созданное, понятное и не совсем (как "страна таинственной духовности").

> Зато с отрицательной в публицистике появилось много ( типа страны плохих дорог и ...), но об этом не будем.

Об этом действительно не нужно.

Спасибо за внимание, [[@Людмила](/users/247/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0)](/users/247/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0).

> "Страна восходящего солнца" - это неофициальное название государства Японии, как и "Соединённое королевство", обозначающее Великобританию.

"Страна восходящего солнца" - одна из самых узнаваемых перифраз, а "Соединённое королевство" - самое что ни на есть официальное наименование туманного Альбиона, однако я положительно не понимаю, для каких причин здесь обсуждаются альтернативные обозначения Японии, Британии, Петербурга... Надо полагать, участники дискуссии таким образом готовят меня к предложению заменить "Россию" чем-то более популярным у любителей многословных выражений.

> В данном контексте, по моему будут смотреться следующие варианты:
>
> *На территории бывшей (павшей) империи, в северной части Евразии, на территории от Москвы до самых до окраин, между Днестром и Амуром*.

*На территории павшей империи* - это смотрится. Просто и... лучше не придумаешь. Благодарствуйте.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Россия — **священная наша держава**,
> Россия — **любимая наша страна**.
> Могучая воля, великая слава —
> Твоё достоянье на все времена!
> Славься, **Отечество наше свободное**,
> **Братских народов союз вековой**,
> Предками данная мудрость народная!
> Славься, страна! Мы гордимся тобой!

Выделил перифразы. Чтобы ответить на вопрос конкретнее, нужно знать в каком контексте этот перифраз должен употребляться.

---

В данном контексте, по моему будут смотреться следующие варианты:

*На территории бывшей (павшей) империи, в северной части Евразии, на территории от Москвы до самых до окраин, между Днестром и Амуром*.

Comment: Это не перифраз. Чкорее обычный эпитет.
У Софьи ближе к теме, но сами по себе неудачные примеры.

Answer (score 3):

ПЕРИФРАЗ:

Страна незаходящего солнца (размеры), двуглавого орла (Восток - Запад) и таинственной духовности (духовный оплот мира).

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

"Народы южных и западных славян, порабощенных турками и Австро-Венгерской империей, еще в XVIII веке с восхищением и надеждой говорили: «РОССИЯ – СТРАНА НЕЗАХОДЯЩЕГО СОЛНЦА». Действительно, когда на западной границе солнце заходит, то на восточном побережье оно уже восходит".

"Двуглавый орел, как символ русской государственности, уходит своими корнями в далекий XV век, во времена Ивана III. Он был изображен на его государственной печати. На одной стороне печати изображался всадник с копьем, поражающий дракона, на другой - двуглавый орел, схвативший двух зайцев.

Впервые это изображение, ставшее символом государства Российского, было замечено еще в наскальных рисунках XIII века до нашей эры. Оно служило гербом хеттским царям. Позднее его использовали в своей символике правители Мидийского царства. По прошествии нескольких веков, двуглавый орел становится символом Римской империи. В Россию он приходит после брака Ивана III с племянницей последнего Византийского императора Софьей Палеолог. Через Софью, последнюю византийскую царевну, к русским князьям приходит титул царя и самодержца всея Руси".
http://www.ote4estvo.ru/gerby-flagi-znamena/876-gerb-rossiyskoy-imperii.html

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (О ДУХОВНОСТИ)

1) http://tainy.net/42685-osobaya-missiya-rossii.html

"Об особой роли России в разные времена говорили многие отечественные мыслители. Впервые идея о том, что именно наша страна озарит мир Божественным светом благодати, а ее столица станет Третьим Римом, прозвучала еще в XVI веке.
Есть философы, которые считают, что у каждой цивилизации есть свой потенциал, который должен быть реализован, своя судьба. Так, немецкий философ Освальд Шпенглер исходил из принципа реализованности. Он считал, что каждая цивилизация имеет свою пружинку времени. Когда уже реализованы все способы бытия и уже все сделано, цивилизация начинает идти на убыль. Если исходить из этого принципа, то недосказанность открывает более широкие перспективы в будущем перед Россией, чем перед Европой. И, по мнению Шпенглера, именно Россия сохранила реализацию своего предназначения. Начиная с Петра I и вплоть до настоящего момента, она занималась осуществлением чужой участи".

2) Бердяев "Душа России"  http://krotov.info/library/02_b/berdyaev/1918_15_01.html

"И поистине можно сказать, что Россия непостижима для ума и неизмерима никакими аршинами доктрин и учений. А верит в Россию каждый по-своему, и каждый находит в полном противоречий бытии России факты для подтверждения своей веры. Подойти к разгадке тайны, скрытой в душе России, можно, сразу же признав антиномичность России, жуткую ее противоречивость".

Comment: >>>Страна незаходящего солнца (размеры), двуглавого орла (Восток - Запад) и таинственной духовности (духовный оплот мира).  
  
Формально - да.
Но - "сперто от и до".
Первое у британцев, второе - у Византии, третье - у Тибета, да и просто не к месту.

Comment: @София, поменял век в исторической справке, в остальном по фактам ошибок не нашёл.

Правда философские опусы довольно странные, что впрочем неудивительно для статьи с названием "Особая миссия России" с сомнительного сайта. В частности концепция Третьего Рима предполагала, что “два Рима падоша, а третий стоит, а четвертому не быта”., т. е. Третий Рим - это и есть Россия, которая уже есть и является оплотом истиной веры, а не появится в будущем как в Вашем тексте. Да и вообще какое отношение ваше "Дополнение о духовности" имеет к духовности непонятно.

Comment: Марк Из, а как вы определяете духовность? И проверьте, пожалуйста, ошибки в следующей "исторической заметке".ПРО ДУХОВНОСТЬ (в свободном изложении).  «Духовность, в общих чертах, относят к области духа,  дух же  –  фундаментальная философская категория, и его можно определить как способность мира и человека к движению. Духовность  в современном понимании – это новый этап отношений человечества с миром и  формирование человека как целеустремленного, самосовершенствующегося существа.

Comment: Движение должно вести не к случайной цели, а к образованию системы более высокого порядка (это называется высшей целесообразностью)».

ПРО ШПЕНГЛЕРА.  Может ли принцип недосказанности и  нереализованности для России послужить основанием для особой исторической миссии, при этом для такой миссии  потребуется  особая  духовность.

Answer (score 3):

Знать бы, действительно, контекст, направленность перифразы (романтическая, патриотическая, сатирическая).

У Лермонтова: Страна рабов, страна господ.

В поэзии часто - Страна берёз. ("страна берёзового ситца")

В советские времена перифраз-идиом, штампов было очень много: страна победившего социализма, страна героев, родина авиации,страна 15 республик, кстати, и сатирическое "родина слонов"тоже оттуда.Самая читающая страна. В послевоенное время- страна, которую нельзя победить; страна-Победитель,Освободительница народов;

Теперь с положительной контаминацией встречается такое: Самая большая страна мира (площадь её составляет 11,5% мировой территории), Страна с самой протяженной сухопутной границей планеты, Родина Пушкина.

Зато с отрицательной в публицистике появилось много ( типа страны плохих дорог и ...), но об этом не будем.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос-то я понял. 
Могу предложить официальное название государства: Российская Федерация.

Или также распространённое слово среди подростков (и не только): Рашка. Но это слово, надо полагать, относится к сленгу.

Comment: Вы не поняли вопроса. Перифраза - это образное описательное выражение. Первый пример не подходит - нет образности. Второй не подходит - одно слово, а должно быть сочетание слов. Да и образность сомнительная - сплошное уничижение.  Пример перифразы:  к слову Япония -  Страна восходящего солнца. К слову Санкт-Петербург - город на Неве.

Comment: А, вот оно что! К Санкт-Петербургу можно подобрать ещё Северная Пальмира ;)

Comment: >>>Рашка. Но это слово, надо полагать, относится к сленгу.  
  
И еще "эта страна"))

Comment: Страна  восходящего  солнца это устойчивое  словосочетание. Можно  сказать:  страна,  где  существует  культ  любования  цветущей  сакурой.  Или - страна  гейш  и  самураев.

Comment: Хороший вариант - "страна гейш и самураев", он короткий  и сразу узнаваемый.

Comment: Bernard, Вы не правы. В данном случае "Страна восходящего солнца" - это неофициальное название государства Японии, как и "Соединённое королевство", обозначающее Великобританию. 

Да, неофициальные слова пишутся без кавычек (извините, что выделил их). Кстати, неофициальные название государств, напоминающие клички людей, пишутся с прописной буквы (только первое слово).

Answer (score 1):

Шестая часть земли (с названьем кратким Русь- С.Есенин).
Русская земля (Слово о полку Игореве)

Answer (score 0):

> > > перифразы к слову

Что-с???

"Родина слонов" не подойдет?